# If the answers were on a mission, what would it be?

Tags: riddle, word

Solve the clues and arrive at a word. Let's call the word **X**.

Combine the letters/words obtained from each clue and arrive at **X**.

> Places with lots of noise and eager eyeballs. Take the last three letters from this word.
>   An article.
>   I'm a cow but quieter. Take the first three letters.

Split the word **X** into two parts namely **X1** and **X2**.

> What would **X1** & **X2** do together?

It does not make logical sense but makes literal sense.

Hint 1:-

> The place with noise and eager eyeballs starts with an 'a'.

Comment: Are the clues in the order of the letters or do we have to rearrange them...

Comment: @Sid They are in order.

Comment: Noise and eager eyeballs? A stadium, maybe?

Comment: @mestackoverflow You're very close :)

Comment: An article? Do you mean synonyms or name of any article?

Comment: @Techidiot without giving much away I'd like to say "that clue is very literal" :)

Comment: Must be a/an... Noise and eager eyeballs sound too broad to me... could be school,stadium,party,crowd,etc...

Comment: @Sid I've added a hint :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My answer:

> Space Shuttle Mission STS-41C

Explanation:

> ARE**NAS** = Places with lots of noise and eager eyeballs
>
>  **A** = An Article
>
>  **BEE**F = A cow but quieter (because it's dead)
>
>  Putting it all together, we get X = NASABEE. So, X1 = NASA and X2 = BEE.
>
>  In 1984, on the *Space Shuttle Mission STS-41C*, NASA's Challenger space shuttle took bees into space as part of a *Shuttle Student Involvement Project Experiment* to study the honeycomb structure built by bees in zero gravity.
>
>  This answer also ties in with the title - If the answers were on a *mission*, what would it *be*? (sounds like bee)
>
> Also:-
> **It does not make logical sense but makes literal sense.**
>  Answer:- Honeymoon

Comment: You got all the words right. But the mission isn't what I had in mind. Remember the mission makes no logical sense with the words. I'm accepting the answer. Can I make some edits to the mission alone (without removing anything, your answer makes absolute sense) :)

Comment: Absolutely, go right ahead